# Authenticating accounts in Ethereum using web3js

Tags: web3js, accounts, authentication

Is a there a way to authenticate accounts in Ethereum using Web3js? Or if there are any other ways to authenticate accounts?

We are building an application where users can register in our system. Once registered, a username and password along with an ethereum account number will be assigned to the user and he can execute transactions.

The username and password will be stored in the external system(non-blockchain).I am looking for a way to authenticate the user in ethereum with their account numbers - something like the username/password combination.

Comment: Please give us some more details on what you want to do exactly. As of now, my answer would be 'yes and yes'

Comment: I have updated the description of the original question

Comment: You can request for the user to sign a message, or send a transaction to a contract (transactions are signed). With that you can validate the users is in possession of the private key that generates the address.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. I found a link which explains signing transactions : 

https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3